# DATASET FROM SSRS TO POWER BI

Tags: sql, powerbi, ssrs-2008

It is possible to copy full raport with dataset from SSRS and recreate it in power bi ?

Comment: Power BI supports SSRS reports, which it calls Paginated Reports. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi

Comment: but it is possible in pbi desktop ?

Comment: In Power BI Desktop you would have to start from scratch.  You can re-use the query from the SSRS Dataset, but everything else you will have to recreate.

Comment: okey i understand, i have CASE like 'CASE
  WHEN @unit='BT' THEN  round([D+1_MAX in BT],2)
  WHEN @unit='CAR' THEN round([D+1_MAX in CAR],2)
  WHEN @unit='PAL' THEN round([D+1_MAX in PAL],2)
  WHEN @unit='kLTR' THEN round([D+1_MAX in LT]/1000,2)
 END as [D+1_MAX]' did you know how i can reacreate it in pbi desktop ?

Comment: Parameters in Power BI and SSRS work completely differently.  In the PowerBI DataSet query you would normally load all the "units" and apply filters or logic in the Power Query or DAX layer.

Comment: what about where,  group by and joins ? it will work if i copy from dataset and I use native query in pbi ?

Comment: Could.  But normally in Power BI you bring in each table seperately into the Data Set, establish the relationships there and then build your report.

Comment: David, its possible to migrate raports from SSRS to power bi without power bi premium subscription ?

Comment: No.  As it says in the doc : "You can publish and share paginated reports in your My Workspace or in other workspaces, as long as the workspace is in a Power BI Premium capacity and you have write access to the workspace."

Comment: Hello, David i used embedded data source and published manually raport to power bi service, but when i openning it on power bi service, i have error like  (((There was an error contacting an underlying data source. Manage your credentials or gateway settings on the management page. Please verify that the data source is available, your credentials are correct and that your gateway settings are valid.)) i need to create a gateway in this case ?